# How to use async http request in Angular HttpInterceptor

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, angular-http-interceptors

I create a http interceptor using Angular 7 to handle Oauth2 token, so a http request is needed to get token and add it into every http request headers.

My solution:

1. get token from `localStorage`.
2. if it's null or has expired, then get token from backend.
3. set token into `localStorage` and set expire date.

**My question** is why interceptor return value always before getting token.

See my code as below:
*auth-interceptor.ts*

```js
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {
  HttpEvent,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpHeaders,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpRequest
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {CommonService} from "../../services/common/common.service";
import {catchError} from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {
  }

  private localDate: Date = new Date();

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    if (req.url.includes('/token')){
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    // 1. get token from localstorage
    let user = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // 2.  1>if expired or null, call get token& save into ls
    if (user && this.validDate()) {
      let userObj = JSON.parse(user);
      let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(userObj);
      let request = req.clone({headers: header});
      return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
        if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403) {
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }));
    } else {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.handleAccess(req,next));
    }
  }

  private async handleAccess(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let token = await this.getToken();
    let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders(JSON.parse(token));
    let changedRequest = request.clone({headers: header});
    return next.handle(changedRequest).toPromise();
  }

  getToken(): Promise<any>{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.commonService.getToken().subscribe(token=>{
        this.localDate = new Date();
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(token));
        resolve(token);
      })
    })
  }

  validDate(): boolean{
    return new Date().valueOf() - this.localDate.valueOf() < 3599 * 1000;
  }
}
```

`getToken()` is a simple http request(`HttpClient`).